# bcp throws random string truncation error when importing into date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am trying to BCP IN a large csv data file.  Please note, this is linux BCP to a remote windows SQL Server engine.

I have a column in the file with a date time value.  example value: `2017-02-03 00:00:00`

the data file has millions of rows.  example text:  `~~306~~2016-01-10 00:00:00~2017-02-03 00:00:00~~`

in what appears as a random act of BCP, I get the following error:  `Invalid character value for cast specification`. if I try again, I'll get `String data, right truncation`

The error is not consistent, however, the format for the date time is.  how do I troubleshoot this?  I assume it would be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` for MSSQL if I am right?

Thanks

Comment: I like to load data into tables where all the columns are strings -- and then do the data type manipulation in the database.

Comment: I do too...my problem is this is a live production web-serving database.  The database owner says I have to minimize the movement.

Comment: Consider `OPENROWSET(BULK...`, it allows you to query the data in such a way that errors become easier to spot than the often cryptic complaints of `bcp`. Note that even if you can't use this in a production server because the file can't be made accessible, you can use it on a test instance of SQL Server to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I would but the server is on host db3 and the file is on host data.  two different machines.

Comment: Hence my second sentence. :-P Note that SQL Server even comes in a Docker container these days. Once you've spotted the problem, you can correct the file, the format, or the process creating the file.

Comment: I'm with Gordon here.  With regards to "minimize movement", you also have to minimize the points of failure.  You could end up chasing ghosts forever.  Would you rather the entire load fail, or a couple of records get suspended for review?

Comment: understood.  taking it back to owner.  thanks

Comment: "minimize movement" - as a selling point to the owner - you most likely will wind up moving more data trying to troubleshoot this on a live system as a single load (start, load some data, fail. start again, load some data fail, etc...). It's a live system, a broken/problematic file should not be forced into it. A test system is necessary as Jeroen stated or 2 movements of the data as Gordon stated.

Comment: And to add to John and Jamie, I wouldn't recommend loading data directly into "live" tables anyway.  Much better to load the data in and *validate* the data before loading into "real" tables.

Comment: That's the idea right now.  It's a staging table I'm loading.   My problem is that BCP appears to be unstable, and decides to flake even though I've maximised the data lengths, and structurized the date fields.  the other issue is I'm SQL 2012, so breaking a full record in SQL Server is not efficient at best.

Comment: I can gaurantee you BCP is not unstable. That executable has been around for a long time. Your destination/staging table should be all varchar (varchar8000 is needed). You shouldnt be getting any data type conversion errors if your destination is all varchar. If you are getting truncation messages either 1 your data actually does have values longer than your varchar fields are set to or 2 you have line termination issues in the file (some line does not terminate properly so data from entire next line is inserted into the last column of this line)... or something like that.

Comment: You should be using the -e option. This will give you line numbers that failed and the line data that failed.It reports "data" errors, not "bcp application" errors. Very useful for this type of troubleshooting. With a line number, you can use proper text file editor to inspect more closely.